# SonarQube, Unit test coverage and integration test coverage separately

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-ops

Is it possible to see/show unit test coverage and integration test coverage separately in SonarQube?
Note; I am using JaCoCo plugin for SonarQube

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://blog.sonarsource.com/sonarqube-6-2-in-screenshots

this possibility was dropped for good reasons in 6.2 -> please take a look at the blog post

// EDIT: i am sorry, i was out of battery, follow-up

The reason why it was consolidated, was the fact, that most plugins, besides the sonar-plugins, provided little to none sufficient distinction between integration, smoke, unit, and whatever coverage.

There used to be a good blog post about it, but i cant find it anymore -> the information about 6.2. is just the version, where they consolidated all of them into just an overall coverage.

So for now, there is no way to separate Coverage into multiple different versions.

Additional reading and better explanation can be found in the jira ticket of sonarsource:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-345

> Some problems
>
> We're dealing with multiple coverage tools that provide non-homogeneous data. Some provide only aggregate, project-level coverage metrics; some provide file-level coverage data; and others provide line-by-line coverage data. Calculating project coverage across multiple languages that use tools that provide disparate data sets is a nightmare.
>
> How do you compute Overall Coverage for conditions? If the Unit Test data says 2 of 4 conditions on a line are covered, and the Integration Test data says 2 of 4 are covered... is that a total coverage of 2, 3, or 4 of 4?
>
> How do you compute coverage for a project when the report(s) only contain data on a subset of files? Are they missing from the data because they're not executable or because they're not covered at all and were 'missed' by the coverage engine?
>
> How do you recognize which files are "testable" in order to force overage to 0 on them? E.G. not all .java files with nLoC are testable (interfaces)
> Some projects only have integration tests; it is their primary means of testing. But Integration Tests are treated differently in terms of metric calculation than Unit tests. How to have a single QG? Solution would be Overall coverage but we are back to aggregation issue. BTW overall coverage is no more displayed in UI.